# ignite filesystem : cluster group is empty

Tags: java, ignite

I'm new to Apache Ignite and I'm trying to use the FileSystem feature.

When I am using the XML config file all works fine, but when turning the conf to JAVA I obtain this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsException: Failed to execute operation because there are no IGFS metadata nodes.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsMetaManager.runClientTask(IgfsMetaManager.java:254)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.mkdirs(IgfsImpl.java:757)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsImpl.mkdirs(IgfsImpl.java:749)
    at com.test.IgniteCacheClass.main(IgniteCacheClass.java:171)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.cluster.ClusterGroupEmptyException: Cluster group is empty.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$5.apply(IgniteUtils.java:765)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$5.apply(IgniteUtils.java:763)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:903)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.call(IgniteComputeImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.igfs.IgfsMetaManager.runClientTask(IgfsMetaManager.java:251)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupEmptyCheckedException: Cluster group is empty.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.emptyTopologyException(IgniteUtils.java:4621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:584)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:428)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.call(IgniteComputeImpl.java:352)
    ... 4 more
```

I've found the solution while writing, but I have another question. It was not working because I launched it with client mode (obviously...). But with the XML, without the client mode explicitly set, I will create an Ignite server node.

So, now I decided to become a client of that server node but I don't want to set all the parameters again. Isn't there a way to connect by just providing the meta and data cache name with the FileSystem name for example? Do you find it dirty if I store (and if it works...) the conf as binary objects ?

I'll be glad if someone could advice me on this topic :)

Best regards

Comment: can you please provide XML config as well as Java config - might be helpful to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening and thank you for your quick reply.

As I said, I found a mistake in my configuration (I think). I put all the same boh configurations if needed. I was starting the node as client but seems to be ran as server first.

Do you know why I now need to provide again all the config when connecting as a client? Is there a way to don't put the entire conf when connecting as a client?

**XML config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
    Ignite Spring configuration file to startup ignite cache.

    When starting a standalone node, you need to execute the following command:
    {IGNITE_HOME}/bin/ignite.{bat|sh} examples/config/filesystem/example-igfs.xml

    When starting Ignite from Java IDE, pass path to this file into Ignition:
    Ignition.start("examples/config/filesystem/example-igfs.xml");
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--
        Optional description.
    -->
    <description>
        Spring file for ignite configuration with client available endpoints.
    </description>

    <!--
        Initialize property configurer so we can reference environment variables.
    -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK"/>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Configuration below demonstrates how to setup a IgniteFs node with file data.
    -->
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">


        <property name="fileSystemConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.FileSystemConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="igfs"/>
                    <property name="metaCacheName" value="igfs-meta"/>
                    <property name="dataCacheName" value="igfs-data"/>

                    <!-- Must correlate with cache affinity mapper. -->
                    <property name="blockSize" value="#{128 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="perNodeBatchSize" value="512"/>
                    <property name="perNodeParallelBatchCount" value="16"/>

                    <!-- Set number of prefetch blocks. -->
                    <property name="prefetchBlocks" value="32"/>

                    <!--
                        Example of configured IPC loopback endpoint.
                    -->
                    <!--
                    <property name="ipcEndpointConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsIpcEndpointConfiguration">
                            <property name="type" value="TCP" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    -->

                    <!--
                        Example of configured shared memory endpoint.
                    -->
                    <!--
                    <property name="ipcEndpointConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsIpcEndpointConfiguration">
                            <property name="type" value="SHMEM" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    -->
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="igfs-data"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                    <property name="affinityMapper">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsGroupDataBlocksKeyMapper">
                            <!-- Haw many blocks in row will be stored on the same node. -->
                            <constructor-arg value="512"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="igfs-meta"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignition provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Java config**

```
IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();

FileSystemConfiguration fsConfig = new FileSystemConfiguration();
fsConfig.setName("igfs");
fsConfig.setMetaCacheName("igfs-meta");
fsConfig.setDataCacheName("igfs-data");
fsConfig.setBlockSize(128 * 1024);
fsConfig.setPerNodeBatchSize(512);
fsConfig.setPerNodeParallelBatchCount(16);
fsConfig.setPrefetchBlocks(32);

CacheConfiguration fsDataCache = new CacheConfiguration();
fsDataCache.setName("igfs-data");
fsDataCache.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
fsDataCache.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
fsDataCache.setBackups(0);
fsDataCache.setAffinityMapper(new IgfsGroupDataBlocksKeyMapper(512));

CacheConfiguration fsMetadataCache = new CacheConfiguration();
fsMetadataCache.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
fsMetadataCache.setName("igfs-meta");
fsMetadataCache.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
fsMetadataCache.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);

config = new IgniteConfiguration();
config.setClientMode(true); 
config.setWorkDirectory("c:/temp/ignite/instance");
config.setFileSystemConfiguration(fsConfig);    
config.setCacheConfiguration(fsDataCache, fsMetadataCache);

TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi=new TcpDiscoverySpi();
discoverySpi.setLocalPort(47506);
discoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(20);
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder=new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

config.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(config);
```

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to set just cache names and IGFS name at the moment. You have to provide full config even for the client node. We will improve that a bit in future, but I doubt we will be able to simplify config down to several strings, because client communicates with the underlying file system, so we have to keep some config anyway.

Vladimir.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Vladimir for your reply, it's what I was regretted. It's not a problem, I'll do with it for the moment and find a way to abstract this layer.  Have a nice day!    Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested on it I put a code I did to make the client easier.

**For the server**

```
IgniteConfiguration configBin = new IgniteConfiguration();
CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration();      
configBin.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfig);

Ignite igniteFSCache = Ignition.start(configBin);
IgniteCache<String, Object> binaryCache = igniteFSCache.getOrCreateCache("confCache").withKeepBinary();

FileSystemConfiguration fsConfig = new FileSystemConfiguration();
fsConfig.setName("igfs");
fsConfig.setMetaCacheName("igfs-meta");
fsConfig.setDataCacheName("igfs-data");
fsConfig.setBlockSize(128 * 1024);
fsConfig.setPerNodeBatchSize(512);
fsConfig.setPerNodeParallelBatchCount(16);
fsConfig.setPrefetchBlocks(32);

binaryCache.put("fsConfig", fsConfig);

CacheConfiguration fsDataCache = new CacheConfiguration();
fsDataCache.setName("igfs-data");
fsDataCache.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
fsDataCache.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
fsDataCache.setBackups(0);
fsDataCache.setAffinityMapper(new IgfsGroupDataBlocksKeyMapper(512));

binaryCache.put("fsDataCache", fsDataCache);

CacheConfiguration fsMetadataCache = new CacheConfiguration();
fsMetadataCache.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
fsMetadataCache.setName("igfs-meta");
fsMetadataCache.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
fsMetadataCache.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);

binaryCache.put("fsMetadataCache", fsMetadataCache);

IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();
config.setWorkDirectory("c:/temp/ignite/instance");
config.setFileSystemConfiguration(fsConfig);    
config.setCacheConfiguration(fsDataCache, fsMetadataCache);
config.setGridName("CacheGrid");


TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi=new TcpDiscoverySpi();
discoverySpi.setLocalPort(47506);
discoverySpi.setLocalPortRange(20);

TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder=new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);    
config.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(config);
```

**For the client**

```
IgniteConfiguration configBin = new IgniteConfiguration();

configBin.setClientMode(true);  
Ignite igniteFSCache = Ignition.start(configBin);
IgniteCache<String, Object> binaryCache = igniteFSCache.getOrCreateCache("confCache").withKeepBinary();

BinaryObject fsConfig =  (BinaryObject)binaryCache.get("fsConfig");
FileSystemConfiguration fsConf = (FileSystemConfiguration)fsConfig.deserialize();
CacheConfiguration fsDataCache =  (CacheConfiguration)binaryCache.get("fsDataCache");    
CacheConfiguration fsMetadataCache =  (CacheConfiguration)binaryCache.get("fsMetadataCache");    

IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();
config.setWorkDirectory("c:/temp/ignite/instance");
config.setFileSystemConfiguration(fsConf);  
config.setCacheConfiguration(fsDataCache, fsMetadataCache);
config.setGridName("CacheGrid");
config.setClientMode(true);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(config);
```

Best regards